# ListContourPlot-ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, color

How can I use ONLY the central 90% of the spectrum, not the whole range? For example, I do not like to see the lowest values in purple, but in deep blue color.

```
tzvw={{394.5, 0.58, -0.56391}, {394.5, 0.56, -0.580086}, {394.5, 
0.54, -0.56415}, {394.5, 0.52, -0.561491}, {394.5, 
0.5, -0.572876}, <<3267>>, {90557.4, 0.1, -0.358004}, {90557.4, 
0.08, -0.2929}, {90557.4, 0.06, -0.240185}, {90557.4, 
0.04, -0.211586}, {90557.4, 0.02, -0.156428}}


 ShowLegend[
 ListContourPlot[tzvw,
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"], 
  Contours -> Range[-2.25, 2.75, 0.25], ContourLines -> False,
  FrameTicks -> {ticklst, Automatic, None, None},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 0.52}, {-2.25, 2.75}}, FrameStyle -> 20,
  AspectRatio -> 0.3, ImageSize -> 700,
  "DelaunayDomainScaling" -> True,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, y <= 0.5]]
```

Comment: This is not valid code. Please post code that can be evaluated and results in useful output (e.g. define `tzvw`).

Answer (score 12):

You can `Rescale` your points that are passed to `ColorFunction` so that they're between `0.05` and `0.95` as in the example below:

```
data = Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}];
ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
    Rescale[#, {0, 1}, {0.05, 0.95}]] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: beat me by 20 seconds. BTW, the default setting for `ColorFunctionScaling` is `True`, so you should use `Rescale[#, {0, 1}, {0.05, 0.95}]` (or set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`).

Comment: @Heike Thanks, I knew I had forgotten something :)

Comment: Looks fine in the first glance but the result is more or less monochrome!

Comment: Thanks R.M but how can I send you the whole tzvw. Then you can see what happens if I apply your approach.

Comment: @K-1 You can't send files through this site. You should try and reduce your problem to a simpler sub-problem that can be easily posted in the question. It needn't even be your actual problem as long as it conveys your problem clearly.

Comment: Or specify the colour range using Blend: `ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Yellow}, #] &)]`

Comment: Thanks R.M. Setting ColorFunctionScaling->False partially solved my problem. More or less I'm satisfied now!

Comment: @K-1 You say partially solved... is there something that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @R.M. since my data contains some spiky points (don't know where) but if I scale it against Maximal/Minimal values, the output won't be satisfactory. So I have to determine those borders by myself.