# Fixed color scale in multiple density plots with Fixed PlotLegends scale

Tags: plotting

From the great answer of Mr. Wizard, I would like to learn how to implement the associated PlotLegends scaled too. Here is the simplest example with PlotLegends, which does not look to be scaled:

```
data = {{{2, 4, 5, 4}, {3, 3, 7, 2}, {7, 2, 6, 5}, {7, 4, 8, 2}}, 
        {{2, 1, 7, 9}, {3, 2, 1, 8}, {3, 3, 9, 7}, {0, 9, 7, 9}}, 
        {{2, 2, 9, 0}, {5, 7, 0, 9}, {6, 9, 1, 9}, {5, 3, 8, 8}}};

Table[ListDensityPlot[Rescale[data[[i]], {0, 9}], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> All, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic], {i, 1, 4}]
```

The first legend shows a different scale from the other three.

Comment: "From the great answer of Mr.Wizard..." — could you please also link to that answer?

Comment: The first legend looks different because the max value is 8/9 < 1, whereas in the rest, it is 9/9 == 1. Perhaps you were looking for the 3 argument form of `Rescale`?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13046/fixed-color-scale-in-multiple-density-plots

Comment: What is crucial is that I am using DensityPlot, not ListDensityPlot (tha was an example), on many functions. But the color scale should be exactly the same on the plots as well as on the plot legends.

Comment: The actual plotting function doesn't really matter, as the issue is that of rescaling. It would be helpful to move the rescaling operation to the color function, as it can then be used with both DP and LDP. Please see the `ColorFunction` I used in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4530/5). Specifically, it uses the 3 argument version of `Rescale` to scale the input so that it is between fixed limits. Of course, this also requires that you know a priori, the min/max of your function/list, but it is easy to workaround it if you don't.

Comment: Yes, you are right! BUT there is an issue: if you use the rescaling function with more arguments, it will make the absolute color in the plot relative to the local min and max.

Comment: sc = {Min /@ data, Max /@ data}\[Transpose]

Comment: Table[ListDensityPlot[Rescale[data[[i]], sc[[i]]], 
              ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> All, 
              ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",     PlotLegends -> Automatic], {i, 1, 4}]

Comment: It seems that in order to keep the absolute color scale on the plot you choose the global min and max. But in doing so, the plot legend is not shown entirely. On the other hand, if you choose the relative min and max, the legend is correct, but the color scheme is shifted and it does not correspond to a unique global scale.

Comment: @Loscuro I believe there is a very small error in your code. Instead of `{i, 1, 4}` you should use `{i, 1, 3}` in your `Table[]` function.

Comment: If you know you functions' min and max, then simply use `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colorfcn, {min,max}}]`. If you want to group them together, then use the technique [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20021/52).

Comment: Don't forget to use the @name convention to notify someone of your comments.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try this:

```
data = {{{2, 4, 5, 4}, {3, 3, 7, 2}, {7, 2, 6, 5}, {7, 4, 8, 2}}, {{2,
  1, 7, 9}, {3, 2, 1, 8}, {3, 3, 9, 7}, {0, 9, 7, 9}}, {{2, 2, 9, 
 0}, {5, 7, 0, 9}, {6, 9, 1, 9}, {5, 3, 8, 8}}};

Table[ListDensityPlot[Rescale[data[[i]], {0, 9}], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> All, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend["TemperatureMap"]], {i, 1, 3}]
```

Result:

[image]

To see all available colors you can use:

```
Table[ListDensityPlot[Rescale[data[[i]], {0, 9}], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> All, ColorFunction -> #, 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[#]], {i, 1, 3}] & /@ 
ColorData["Gradients"]
```

[image]