# rescaling ColorFunction for ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I have this question that I've been struggling with. I came across many similar questions, but those solutions do not work for me. What I looked at:

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757097/dynamic-or-forced-scaling-of-colorfunction)

[Example 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29186/how-to-color-a-contour-plot-over-a-subset-of-colors-displayed-in-the-bar-legend)

[Example 3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4529/listcontourplot-colorfunction)

I apologize if I missed something and appreciate your help. The question actually consists of two parts.

**Part 1**

I want to plot a function using `ListContourPlot`.

[data set](http://dropfile.to/3Cmbk)

[alternative link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikomi7rw9a31dxu/lih-3re.cas410.6-31gs.zxdat?dl=1)

```
bulk3ReCAS = Import["/home/molkee/Desktop/ms-alee/data/plane/lih.3re.cas410.6-31gs.zxdat", "Table"];
alee3ReCAS = bulk3ReCAS[[All, {1, 2, 3}]];
density3ReCAS = bulk3reCAS[[All, {1, 2, 4}]];
cntrValue = 0.0005;
dencntr3reCAS = 
ListContourPlot[density3ReCAS, Contours -> {cntrValue}, 
ContourShading -> {White, None}];

minCf = Min[alee3ReCAS[[All, 3]]];
maxCf = Max[alee3ReCAS[[All, 3]]];

aleemap3ReCAS = ListContourPlot[alee3ReCAS,
InterpolationOrder -> 3,
Contours -> 10,
ContourLabels -> Automatic,
AspectRatio -> 1,
ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
   Rescale[#1, {minCf, maxCf}, {0, 1}]] &),
ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
ClippingStyle -> Automatic,
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {minCf, maxCf}}, 9, 
  LegendMargins -> 10, 
  LabelStyle -> 
   Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14], 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 300, LegendMargins -> 0, 
  LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below],
PlotRangePadding -> None,
ImagePadding -> None,
Frame -> False];
```

I want my color function span **the whole range from min to max in my data set**.

I tried to achieve this by

```
ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
Rescale[#1, {minCf, maxCf}, {0, 1}]] &),
ColorFunctionScaling -> False
```

but with no success. This is what I am getting on output: 
[image: output]

However, I was expecting something like this (disregard the labels).

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I also make the colorbar display the full spectrum of colors?

**Part 2**

How can I use the same code to plot the same function, but in some particular region? Let me explain. Suppose my data set is in [0,1]. I want  to see how the data change in [0.5,0.7] so that all values below 0.5 are purple and those above 0.7 are red as far as the rainbow palette is considered.

My question can be best illustrated by the following image, where the same is accomplished when going from [-1:1] to [0:1]:

[image]

Again, I tried many things, but didn't succeed.

Comment: You used a storage service with expiration date. That isn't convenient as the data will be unavailable in a few hours and this site relies on freezing all the relevant info "forever", so anyone will be able to answer anytime in the future. Please use Pastebin or similar ones

Comment: @Dr.belisarius done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1**

With the data and code above , I obtain the plot

[image]

which is similar to that in the question, but not identical.  The corresponding plot with the full range of colors can be obtained from

```
ListContourPlot[alee3ReCAS, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Contours -> 10, Frame -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, 9, LegendMargins -> 10, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive["Helvetica", 14], LegendMarkerSize -> 300], Below]]
```

[image]

The `BarLegend` also is meaningful now.

**Part 2**

To obtain a plot with colors compressed to a narrower range, say `{-2,-1}`, use

```
tem = {#[[1]], #[[2]], Clip[#[[3]], {-2, -1}]} & /@ alee3ReCAS;
ListContourPlot[tem, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Contours -> 10, Frame -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, 9, 
    LegendMargins -> 10, LabelStyle -> Directive["Helvetica", 14], 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 300], Below]]
```

[image]

Note that the many closely spaced contours appear as a small black ring near the center of the plot.

**Addendum**

As requested in a comment below, this same Part 2 result can be obtained with

```
ListContourPlot[alee3ReCAS, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Contours -> Range[-2, -1, 1/9], 
    PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][2 + Clip[#, {-2, -1}]] &), 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {-2, -1}}, 9, LegendMargins -> 10, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive["Helvetica", 14], LegendMarkerSize -> 300], Below]]
```

It is important to remember that, with `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, `ColorFunction` should be scaled manually to range between `0` and `1`.

Comment: Thank you, @bbgodfrey! I really want to understand how to achieve what you have  done in **Part 2** using `Rescale` and `ColorFunctionScaling` like in the examples above. If you know the answer, can you help?

Comment: @molkee Yes, specifying PlotRange is the key issue for Part 1 in that it assures that all values in the list are plotted, after which `ColorFunction` automatically takes care of the rest.  I also have added the second approach that you requested for Part 2.  The same could be done for Part 1, but there is no point in doing so.  Finally, note that I simplified the `BarLegend` code a bit.

Comment: thank you for your kind help! I appreciate it.